# How to display superscripted text in MS Chart?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, mschart, superscript

I'm building charts in my application using `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting`.
I need certain text elements, such as Legends, to contain superscripted text.

How can I do this?

So far I've tried using HTML tags, but it doesn't recognize them - the tags are displayed as-is. I'm also unable to find any `bool` property to allow HTML formatted strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't any built-in function.
The only way is to handle the PostPaint event and draw your own text using some renderer supporting complex formatting.

For example you could use [HtmlRenderer](http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/) that is able to draw html on Graphics objects.

Here's an example of usage:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // subrscribe PostPaint event
    this.chart1.PostPaint += new EventHandler<ChartPaintEventArgs>(chart1_PostPaint);

    // fill the chart with fake data
    var values = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new { X = x, Y = x }).ToList();
    this.chart1.Series.Clear();
    this.chart1.DataSource = values;
    // series name will be replaced
    var series = this.chart1.Series.Add("SERIES NAME"); 
    series.XValueMember = "X";
    series.YValueMembers = "Y";
}

void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = e.ChartElement as LegendCell;
    if (cell != null && cell.CellType == LegendCellType.Text)
    {
        // get coordinate of cell rectangle
        var rect = e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsoluteRectangle(e.Position.ToRectangleF());
        var topLeftCorner = new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Top);
        var size = new SizeF(rect.Width, rect.Height);

        // clear the original text by coloring the rectangle (yellow just to highlight it...)
        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, rect);

        // prepare html text (font family and size copied from Form.Font)
        string html = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "<div style=\"font-family:{0}; font-size:{1}pt;\">Series <sup>AAA</sup></div>",
            this.Font.FontFamily.Name,
            this.Font.SizeInPoints);

        // call html renderer
        HtmlRenderer.HtmlRender.Render(e.ChartGraphics.Graphics, html, topLeftCorner, size);
    }
}
```

and here's a snapshot of the result:

[image]